# How to use SET OPTION within a DB2 stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2, db2-luw, isolation-level

I read (and tried) that I cannot use **WITH UR** in DB2 stored procedures. I am told that I can use **SET OPTION** to achieve the same. However, when I implement it in my stored procedure, it fails to compile (I moved around its location same error). My questions are:

- Can I really not use WITH UR after my SELECT statements within a procedure?
- Why is my stored procedure failing to compile with the below error
  message?

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MySchema.MySampleProcedure()
        DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1 
        LANGUAGE SQL 
        SET OPTION COMMIT=*CHG 
        
        BEGIN
             DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP_TABLE AS (
             SELECT 'testValue' as "Col Name"
             ) WITH DATA
        

        BEGIN
             DECLARE  exitCursor CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR
             SELECT *
             FROM SESSION.TEMP_TABLE;
             OPEN exitCursor;
        END;

        END 
        @

Error Message:
```

> SQL0104N  An unexpected token "SET OPTION COMMIT=*CHG" was found
> following "    LANGUAGE SQL

Here is code/error when I use **WITH UR**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MySchema.MySampleProcedure()

    LANGUAGE SQL 
    DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1 

--#SET TERMINATOR @
BEGIN

    DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP_TABLE AS (
        SELECT UTI AS "Trade ID" FROM XYZ WITH UR
        ) WITH DATA;

    BEGIN
        DECLARE  exitCursor CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR
            SELECT *
            FROM SESSION.TEMP_TABLE;
        OPEN exitCursor;
    END;

END
@
```

line 9 is where the DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY ... is

> DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was
> not a  valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it
> returned: SQL0109N  The statement or command was not processed because
> the following  clause is not supported in the context where it is
> used: "WITH ISOLATION USE  AND KEEP".  LINE NUMBER=9.  SQLSTATE=42601

Comment: Which platform of Db2 ( i series/AS400  ,  Z/OS,  or Linux/Unix/Windows ?  You must __always__ give this information when asking for help with Db2.

Comment: It is Linux/Windows (DB2 LUW 8.x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Specifying the isolation level](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/t0005269.html):

> For static SQL:
>
> - If an isolation-clause is specified in the statement, the value of that clause is used.
> - **If an isolation-clause is not specified in the statement, the isolation level that was specified for the package when the package was bound to the database is used.**

You need to bind the routine package with UR, since your `DECLARE GTT` statement is static. Before `CREATE OR REPLACE` use the following in the same session:

```
CALL SET_ROUTINE_OPTS('ISOLATION UR')
```

P.S.: If you want to run your routine not only 1 time in the same session without an error, use additional `WITH REPLACE` option of `DECLARE`.

Comment: Just to confirm, this call is required only once before compiling the stored procedure. Users could simply call the stored procedure not needing to worry about the isolation level ?

Comment: Yes. Think about this as env setting for the routine creation. All static statements inside the routine will use this isolation level, if they don't use explicit isolation level specification at the statement level.

Comment: Thank you @Mark! I will test this solution and accept this answer if all good.

Answer (score 1):

If your Db2 server runs on Linux/Unix/Windows (Db2-LUW), then there is no such statement as `SET OPTION COMMIT=*CHG` , and so Db2 will throw an exception for that invalid syntax.

It is important to **only** use the matching Db2 Knowledge Centre  for your Db2 platform and your Db2-version. Don't use Db2-Z/OS documentation for Db2-LUW development. The syntax and functionalities differ per platform and per version.

A Db2-LUW SQL PL procedure can use `with ur` in its internal queries, and if you are getting an error then something else is wrong. You have to use `with ur` in the correct syntax however, i.e in a statement that supports this clause.  For your example you get the error because the clause does not appear to be valid in the depicted context. You can achieve the desired result in other ways, one of them being to populate the table in a separate statement from the declaration (e.g `insert into session.temp_table("Trade ID") select uti from xyz with ur;` ) and other ways are also possible.

One reason to use the online Db2 Knowledge Cenbtre documentation is that it includes sample programs, including sample SQL PL procedures, which are also available in source code form in the `sample` directory of your DB2-LUW server, in addition to being available on github.  It is wise to study these, and get them working for you.

Comment: That will explain why SET OPTION is failing to compile. I again added WITH UR at the end of my SELECT statement I get an error and points to the line where temp table is declared: [SQL0109N  The statement or command was not processed because the following clause is not supported in the context where it is used: "WITH ISOLATION USE AND KEEP".]

Comment: Without seeing the *exact full* statement in context, I'm assuming you are using it incorrectly.

Comment: I added the full statement and error when using WITH UR to the question. Would appreciate if you could have a look @Mao.

Comment: I could use ISOLATION LEVEL UR as an option at the very top of the stored procedure to achieve the same, right ? ref: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_createproceduresqlnative.html

Comment: DB2 v11.1.4.5 that is the exact version. 8.x was driver used in dbeaver (I miss understood that).